# Ajax - Php Call method safe?

Tags: php, ajax

I am looking to start ajax for the first time. I will be using it to do a server side validation of a field in a form. Basically, the ajax delivers the input that the users gives, and some php code carries out an if else rule to and sends a response back accordingly. In my php code, some strings will contain sensitive data, will users be able to read or see these strings in anyway?

Thanks for all the helpful answers, it's now very clear :).

Comment: What you don't print out people won't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

> In my php code, some strings will contain sensitive data

Yes, users can see what the server responds with if they try. BUT, if you sensitive data is in PHP code and is never part of the response they'll not be able to see it.

Although, **never put sensitive information in the source either** because anyone who has access to your source code in PHP will be able to have that information. A creepy web hosting company can theoretically do that if they want.

#### Tip

Since you are starting out I would like to mention you should [use jQuery to do your Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) stuff.

### Attempt to explain Ajax

When you make an Ajax call you send a request using the HTTP protocol after the page load. JavaScript makes the request, receives a response and makes changes to the HTML DOM that's loaded in the browser without a refresh.

```
Requests: Ajax function --(HTTP(S))--> SERVER --(HTTP(S))--> Ajax function

Action: Ajax function --> interpret response and manipulate DOM accordingly
```

So in other words, it's just like a request made by the browser in terms of protocol, just that it's a Ajax function doing it. So whatever applied to these requests from the browser applies here too.

Typically the response is a JSON string since that's easy for the Ajax function to interpret as it's JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax uses HTTP just like a full page refresh does. If you're sending and/or receiving sensitive data you need to make sure you use SSL for your Ajax calls just like you would for a  secure form submission.

Comment: The actual page will be in ssl. The sensitive string will only be in the php file, and based on its validation, the response will be sent to ajax. Is there any possibility that the string will be viewable, or is it just the responses given from the validation?

Comment: Nope. Since it is not transmitted it is hidden from snoopers.

Comment: @theoth if you don't output the string, it won't be viewable. Just like anything else in PHP - the fact that it's AJAX has no bearing on the matter.

Comment: Also, do I need to set the ajax to use ssl aswell?

Comment: You should since the page may evolve into actually sending sensitive data at some point in the future and some browsers *may* complain about non-secure data being transmitted. But for this particular case it wouldn't be truly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax uses HTTP and the response of AJAX request contains only the data that is generated by the PHP script. If your not echoing the strings that contain sensitive data then there is no way the response would contain them.

If you want to transfer sensitive data then you must use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The page will be in ssl, do I need to set the ajax to use ssl aswell?

Comment: @theoth if your using SSL then use it for all the AJAX requests, all request/responses would be encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensitive data is in php on server side it should be fine.
Just dont return to ajax any sensitive info.

PHP is processed on server side, any requests to php from ajax execute the php scripts on server and return the results of the processing. Client can not see php code.